# How does language learning in a classroom affect self-learning?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, classroom, side-effects

Circumstances require me to take a ~3 month break from my formal/classroom/directed language studies soon. Prior to studying my L2* under a teacher I was learning independently. How will my classroom experience affect my independent study? Considering I still have one semester of classroom learning before my break, what can I do to prepare myself for the transition back to learning by myself?

<sup>* Japanese</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to talk to the teacher, especially if you are planning to rejoin the class in the future.

Explain that you're having to take some time out and ask what you could do to keep up, what top

Comment: Your answer seems to be cut short; "what topics..."